# load decimal into oracle table with sql loader

Tags: oracle, csv, decimal, sql-loader

I have this table in oracle :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
TSTAMP  Date,
prmc1 VARCHAR2(30),
prmc2 VARCHAR2(30),
prmc3 VARCHAR2(30),
prmc4 VARCHAR2(30),
prmc5 NUMBER,
prmc5 NUMBER,
prmc6 NUMBER
)
```

the control file is below :

```
load data
append
 into table mytable
fields terminated by ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS
 ( tstamp DATE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI" TERMINATED BY ",",
   prmc1 ":prmc1",
prmc2 ":prmc2",
prmc3 ":prmc3",
prmc4 ":prmc4",
prmc5 INTEGER  ":prmc5",
prmc6 INTEGER  ":prmc6"
)
```

the value of the column prmc5 in the csv file is -106.436

how do i load this into the table?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify it as [DECIMAL EXTERNAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch06.htm#1007111)

I am also removing specifying the format as the column itself.

```
load data
append
 into table mytable
fields terminated by ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS
 ( tstamp DATE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI" TERMINATED BY ",",
   prmc1 ,
prmc2 ,
prmc3 ,
prmc4 ,
prmc5 DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
prmc6 DECIMAL EXTERNAL
)
```

More details with some Example [here](http://psoug.org/reference/sqlloader.html)

Comment: Oops.. it should be DECIMAL DECIMAL

Comment: the file is loaded but i don't get the appropriate value : in the column in the csv i have : 0.000123 but i get in the table 623915057

Comment: 2014-02-18 23:00,MAR_RNC02,CAS-1178_U-3,20178,CAS-1178_U,100%,0.0954,84230,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,80,0,0,0,0,0,4,84,84,84,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,340.4834,9.924,0,0,7,2,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1542,0.1542,-104.0877,0.1833,0.025,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,20

Comment: what is the column value stored, for this record? After loading

Comment: the value of the 7th column is 623915057

Comment: It is strange! Are you sure, you see the right data, all decimal fields are like this?

Comment: i tried this :TotalMBytes POSITION(64) CHAR TERMINATED BY "," "to_number(substr(:TotalMBytes, 1, length(:TotalMBytes)-4),'999999.999999')"

Comment: Okay, DECIMAL external itself worked for me perfectly.. So, you try the above after decimal external?

Comment: whats the datatype of the table? ( i use number in oracle)

Comment: just number.. also either it should throw issues, or load correctly.. but this can never happen..